# JAVA OffsetDateTime custom hundredth of second

Tags: java, datetime-format, datetimeoffset

I am currently looking for a custom format of date and I can't obtain it.

I want to obtain `"1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00"` using the following code :

```
OffsetDateTime o = OffsetDateTime.now();
String l = o.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
```

The result is:

> 2017-03-28T16:23:57.489+02:00

Very close, but I only need to have `hh:mm:ss.XX`, and not `hh:mm:ss.XXX`.

Do you know how to customize `OffsetDateTime`? I can't find good examples.

Comment: I think nothing wrong with your code, the milliseconds are vary time to time sometime you get XXX but if you compile your code again you will get XX. here is mine 2017-03-28T19:36:00.45+05:00.

Answer (score 1):

[Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43072778/7605325) is **almost** correct. If you take a look at [`DateTimeFormatter` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns), you'll see that the lowercase `s` corresponds to the **seconds**, and uppercase `S`, to the **fraction of seconds**:

```
Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
------  -------                     ------------      -------
s       second-of-minute            number            55
S       fraction-of-second          fraction          978
```

So, in your pattern, `s` and `S` are inverted. The correct pattern is:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSXXX");
OffsetDateTime o = OffsetDateTime.now();
System.out.println(o.format(formatter));
```

The output is:

> 2017-06-19T20:34:29.75-03:00

---

**PS:** Note that the fraction of second is `75` - greater than `59`, which is the maximum value for **seconds** (In your answer, it **seems** correct because the fraction of second is `48`, which gives the impression that it worked).

Another detail is that the offset in my case is `-03:00` because of my system's default timezone. Anyway, just fix your pattern and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem.

It seems that with the pattern:

```
String ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME_WITH_HUNDREDTH_OF_SECOND = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SS.ssXXX";

DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME_WITH_HUNDREDTH_OF_SECOND);


String ll = o.format(dateTimeFormatter);
System.out.println(ll);
```

I have the desired output:

> 2017-03-28T16:44:48.30+02:00

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer `HH:mm:SS.ss` should be `HH:mm:ss.SS`.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.

I fixed it.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String custom = dateTimeFormatter.format(OffsetDateTime.now());
```

You can create other formats that You want in this `.ofPattern("--format--")`

Referrence: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Work for me.